# ICU collation - is there a way to compare numeric strings in numeric order such that leading 0s are taken into account?

Tags: c++, c, locale, collation, icu

I am trying to create a collator that compares numbers in strings with numeric order, but not ignore leading zeros.

For example - 001 < 01 < 002 < 0011 ...

At first I tried the following:

```
UCollator *coll = ucol_open(locale, &err);
ucol_setAttribute(coll, UCOL_NUMERIC_COLLATION, UCOL_ON, &err);
res = ucol_strcoll(coll, s1, -1, s2, -1);
```

However, for s1 = 001 and s2 = 01, ucol_strcoll returned 0, while the desired result is -1.

Next I tried to modify the collator's rules by adding
`& 00 < 0`
However the result was the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I only tested following comparison.
" 002 < 0011"
Here is the complete minimum example.

```
/*
/home/jian/Desktop/regress_pgsql/icu_coll.c

gcc -Wextra /home/jian/Desktop/regress_pgsql/icu_coll.c -licuio -licui18n -licuuc -licudata && ./a.out
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "unicode/ustring.h"
#include "unicode/utypes.h"
#include "unicode/uloc.h"
#include "unicode/ucol.h"
#include "unicode/ucnv.h"
#include "unicode/ucnv_err.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

int
main(void)
{

    UCollator   *mycollator = 0;  
    const char *locale  = "en@colNumeric=yes";

    UErrorCode  status  = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    mycollator  =  ucol_open(locale,&status);

    assert(status <= U_ZERO_ERROR);
    
    int result;
    const   char    *source;
    const   char    *target;
    source  = "002";
    target  = "0011";

    int32_t     sourceLength    = (int32_t) strlen(source);
    int32_t     targetLength    = (int32_t) strlen(target);

    result  = ucol_strcollUTF8(mycollator, source, sourceLength, target, targetLength,&status);

    assert(status <=U_ZERO_ERROR);

    if (result == 0)
        printf("result is UCOL_EQUAL\n");
    else if (result == 1)
        printf("result is UCOL_GREATER\n");
    else
        printf("result is UCOL_LESS\n");

    return 0;
}
```

main function reference: https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4c/ucol_8h.html#a85ed590f640f6339d5c9447177e93864

"en@colNumeric=yes" reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html

to make sure "en@colNumeric=yes" works fine, you probably need

```
    int cnt = ucol_countAvailable();
    printf("ucol_countAvailable %d\n", cnt);
    for(int j = 0; j < cnt; j ++)
    {
        printf("%03d locale: %s\n",j,ucol_getAvailable(j));
    }
```